# Divi headers already sent

Tags: php, wordpress, divi-theme

I made the mistake to update Divi last night on a already running site and since that, I'm struggling with a lot of bugs.

So my biggest Problems are these errors now:

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers
> already sent (output started at
> /home/ganzeinf/public_html/wp-content/themes/Divi/header.php:1)
>
> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already
> sent by (output started at
> /home/ganzeinf/public_html/wp-content/themes/Divi/header.php:1)

Has anyone a clue what I can do?

Or is there a save method to reinstall everything?

I'm new with Wordpress and Divi.

here are the first Lines of wp-content/themes/Divi/header.php:1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<?php
    elegant_description();
    elegant_keywords();
    elegant_canonical();
```

I tried to fix that for 6 hours and deactivate/remove all plugins multiple times.

No I don't looked in every required php file from divi etc. but I don't think that there is a redirected to another site in any relevant file.

I tried a lot of backups even half a year ago. But with every Backup I get a Problem with the Divi Visual Builder it's totally buggy then, which wasn't before.
And yes I tried if this has to do with the cash/cookies from my browser, I also tried it with other Pcs.

Comment: Hello to StackOverflow, can you paste the first 3 lines of `wp-content/themes/Divi/header.php:1`? Do you have whitespaces before the php tag?

Comment: Recently added plugin remove and check

Comment: Any redirect to other page code using function.php or other file?

Comment: _“Or is there a save method to reinstall everything?”_ - the safe method to first of all get the site up & running again, would be that you restore it from your _backup_. If you didn’t make any, then you are paying the price for approaching a thing like this so naively now … Assuming this update did not make any major database updates that are directly related to any changed functionality, you should probably get yourself the code of the previous version of your theme now, and extract all the files over the existing installation. (Backup before that now, at least.)

Comment: I edited my Post and answered all your questions.
I also posted another question in which I described the bug which occurs if I load a Backup.

Comment: Please try to reinstall the divi theme maybe it will be fine.